# TPU strange behavior and memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tpu

I am trying to understand better how TPU "works" during training (Deep Learning) in order to compare with gpus.
https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/system-architecture

For instance, let"s say we have a TPU v2-8. So we have 8 TPU cores, with 64 GB  hbm (memory) so each core has 8 GB hbm.

During training the batch is divided by the number of cores ( 8 ).

At the  beginning, I thought that TPU was like CPU, we have an amount of memory and we have one model in the memory which computes a batch. But from this link : https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting#available-functionality ,

> Each Cloud TPU is made of eight TPU cores, which each have 8GB of RAM
> (or HBM, High-Bandwidth Memory). This memory is used to store the
> weight (variable) tensors, as well as intermediate result tensors
> needed for gradient computation. If the model is too large to fit into
> TPU RAM, the initialization fails and the above error message is
> printed. See the section on reducing memory usage for more help.

It make me think it is like having 8 different memory. So in a way, can we say that it is like doing multi gpus computing with 8 gpus (each of 8gb of memory) ?
***Moreover, how the model is trained ? If there is a replica on each core does it mean that the loss on each replica is averaged in order to do then the correction of the weight ? Does only one model is corrected and then replicate in each other core or Each core correct the average loss ? (which will result in having the same corrected model in each core)***

I have also tried to use on GCP different simple model using gpus/tpu (cnn, rnn, mlp) and I found few strange behaviors about the memory.

For instance:

- with the same RNN, I can feed on the TPU high batch size (125*8) a model composed of 3 BiLSTM with 1024 units. I could not feed the gpu (K80)
- and inversely with an Multi Perceptron Layer, I can  use a bigger batch size with the gpu (k80/v100) than the tpu.
  So does that mean having 8 gb hmb is totally different from 8 gb of VRAM  ? Because given my two example the tpu can use sometimes bigger batch size than gpu and sometimes smaller batch size ?

Example of error message on TPU:

```
> ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-1-5929dd41a578> in <module>() 102 if TPU: 103  
> model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, # steps_per_epoch
> = len(X_train)// batch_size, # .astype(np.float32)
> --> 104      epochs=5, verbose=1) 105 else: 106   model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, #.astype(np.float32) steps_per_epoch
> = len(X_train)// batch_size, 
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py
> in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
> validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
> sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
> validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing,
> **kwargs) 725         max_queue_size=max_queue_size, 726         workers=workers,
> --> 727         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing) 728  729   def evaluate(self,
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py
> in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
> validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
> sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
> validation_freq, **kwargs) 668            
> steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 669            
> validation_steps=validation_steps,
> --> 670             validation_freq=validation_freq) 671  672     return training_arrays.fit_loop(
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py
> in experimental_tpu_fit_loop(model, dataset, epochs, verbose,
> callbacks, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, val_dataset,
> validation_steps, validation_freq) 241         prev_step_count =
> step_count 242       try:
> --> 243         _, outputs = K.batch_get_value([train_op, output_tensors]) 244       except errors.OutOfRangeError: 245        
> logging.warning('Your dataset iterator ran out of data; '
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py
> in batch_get_value(tensors) 3183     raise RuntimeError('Cannot get
> value inside Tensorflow graph function.') 3184   if tensors:
> -> 3185     return get_session(tensors).run(tensors) 3186   else: 3187     return []
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py
> in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata) 954     try:
> 955       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
> --> 956                          run_metadata_ptr) 957       if run_metadata: 958         proto_data =
> tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py
> in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata) 1178 
> if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
> 1179       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets,
> final_fetches,
> -> 1180                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata) 1181     else: 1182       results = []
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py
> in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options,
> run_metadata) 1357     if handle is None: 1358       return
> self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
> -> 1359                            run_metadata) 1360     else: 1361       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py
> in _do_call(self, fn, *args) 1382                    
> '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.' 1383                
> 'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
> -> 1384       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) 1385  1386   def _extend_graph(self):
> 
> ResourceExhaustedError: From /job:worker/replica:0/task:0: Compilation
> failure: Ran out of memory in memory space hbm. Used 8.36G of 8.00G
> hbm. Exceeded hbm capacity by 371.38M.
> 
> Total hbm usage >= 8.36G: reserved        528.00M  program          
> 2.86G  arguments         4.99G (99.8% utilization)
> 
> Output size 4.99G (99.8% utilization); shares 4.99G with arguments.
> 
> Program hbm requirement 2.86G: reserved           4.0K global         
> 84.0K scoped            45.0K HLO temp          2.86G (100.0% utilization, 0.0% fragmentation (201.0K))
> 
> Largest program allocations in hbm:
> 
> 1. Size: 1.43G Operator: op_type="CrossReplicaSum" op_name="training/Adam/CrossReplicaSum_1" Shape:
> f32[38400,10000]{0,1:T(8,128)} Unpadded size: 1.43G XLA label:
> %all-reduce.9 = f32[38400,10000]{0,1:T(8,128)}
> all-reduce(f32[38400,10000]{0,1:T(8,128)} %convolution.13),
> replica_groups={{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}}, to_apply=%sum.387,
> metadata={op_type="CrossReplicaSum"
> op_name="training/Adam/CrossReplicaSum_1"}, backend_config...
> Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 2. Size: 1.43G Operator: op_type="MatMul" op_name="training/Adam/gradients/gradients/dense_1/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1" Shape: f32[38400,10000]{0,1:T(8,128)} Unpadded size: 1.43G XLA label:
> %convolution.13 = f32[38400,10000]{0,1:T(8,128)}
> convolution(bf16[25,38400]{1,0:T(8,128)(2,1)} %reshape.220,
> bf16[25,10000]{1,0:T(8,128)(2,1)} %get-tuple-element.139),
> dim_labels=fb_io->bf, metadata={op_type="MatMul"
> op_name="training/Adam/gradients/gradie... Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 3. Size: 4.0K XLA label: profiler Allocation type: reserved
> ==========================
> 
> 4. Size: 4.0K Operator: op_type="ResourceApplyAdam" op_name="training/Adam/Adam/update_output/kernel/ResourceApplyAdam"
> Shape: (f32[2000,1]{0,1:T(2,128)}, f32[2000,1]{0,1:T(2,128)},
> f32[2000,1]{0,1:T(2,128)}) Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label: %fusion.48 =
> (f32[2000,1]{0,1:T(2,128)}, f32[2000,1]{0,1:T(2,128)},
> f32[2000,1]{0,1:T(2,128)}) fusion(f32[2000,1]{0,1:T(2,128)}
> %get-tuple-element.158, f32[]{:T(256)} %divide.5,
> f32[2000,1]{0,1:T(2,128)} %get-tuple-element.176, f32[]{:T(256)}
> %subtract.24,... Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 5. Size: 4.0K Operator: op_type="ResourceApplyAdam" op_name="training/Adam/Adam/update_embeddings/embeddings/ResourceApplyAdam"
> Shape: (f32[10000,128]{1,0:T(8,128)}, f32[10000,128]{1,0:T(8,128)},
> f32[10000,128]{1,0:T(8,128)}) Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label:
> %fusion.14 = (f32[10000,128]{1,0:T(8,128)},
> f32[10000,128]{1,0:T(8,128)}, f32[10000,128]{1,0:T(8,128)})
> fusion(f32[10000,128]{1,0:T(8,128)} %get-tuple-element.154,
> f32[]{:T(256)} %divide.5, f32[10000,128]{1,0:T(8,128)}
> %get-tuple-element.172, f32[]{:T(256)... Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 6. Size: 4.0K Operator: op_type="ResourceApplyAdam" op_name="training/Adam/Adam/update_dense/kernel/ResourceApplyAdam"
> Shape: (f32[38400,10000]{0,1:T(8,128)},
> f32[38400,10000]{0,1:T(8,128)}, f32[38400,10000]{0,1:T(8,128)})
> Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label: %fusion.2 =
> (f32[38400,10000]{0,1:T(8,128)}, f32[38400,10000]{0,1:T(8,128)},
> f32[38400,10000]{0,1:T(8,128)}) fusion(f32[38400,10000]{0,1:T(8,128)}
> %get-tuple-element.153, f32[]{:T(256)} %divide.5,
> f32[38400,10000]{0,1:T(8,128)} %get-tuple-element.162, f32[...
> Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 7. Size: 4.0K Operator: op_type="ResourceApplyAdam" op_name="training/Adam/Adam/update_dense/bias/ResourceApplyAdam"
> Shape: (f32[10000]{0:T(1024)}, f32[10000]{0:T(1024)},
> f32[10000]{0:T(1024)}) Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label: %fusion.39 =
> (f32[10000]{0:T(1024)}, f32[10000]{0:T(1024)}, f32[10000]{0:T(1024)})
> fusion(f32[10000]{0:T(1024)} %get-tuple-element.152, f32[]{:T(256)}
> %divide.5, f32[10000]{0:T(1024)} %get-tuple-element.160,
> f32[]{:T(256)} %subtract.24, f32[10000]{0:T(1024... Allocation type:
> HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 8. Size: 4.0K Operator: op_type="ResourceApplyAdam" op_name="training/Adam/Adam/update_dense3/kernel/ResourceApplyAdam"
> Shape: (f32[5000,2000]{1,0:T(8,128)}, f32[5000,2000]{1,0:T(8,128)},
> f32[5000,2000]{1,0:T(8,128)}) Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label:
> %fusion.10 = (f32[5000,2000]{1,0:T(8,128)},
> f32[5000,2000]{1,0:T(8,128)}, f32[5000,2000]{1,0:T(8,128)})
> fusion(f32[5000,2000]{1,0:T(8,128)} %get-tuple-element.151,
> f32[]{:T(256)} %divide.5, f32[5000,2000]{1,0:T(8,128)}
> %get-tuple-element.170, f32[]{:T(256)... Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 9. Size: 4.0K Operator: op_type="ResourceApplyAdam" op_name="training/Adam/Adam/update_dense3/bias/ResourceApplyAdam"
> Shape: (f32[2000]{0:T(1024)}, f32[2000]{0:T(1024)},
> f32[2000]{0:T(1024)}) Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label: %fusion.52 =
> (f32[2000]{0:T(1024)}, f32[2000]{0:T(1024)}, f32[2000]{0:T(1024)})
> fusion(f32[2000]{0:T(1024)} %get-tuple-element.150, f32[]{:T(256)}
> %divide.5, f32[2000]{0:T(1024)} %get-tuple-element.168, f32[]{:T(256)}
> %subtract.24, f32[2000]{0:T(1024)} %ge... Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 10. Size: 4.0K Operator: op_type="ResourceApplyAdam" op_name="training/Adam/Adam/update_dense2/kernel/ResourceApplyAdam"
> Shape: (f32[10000,5000]{0,1:T(8,128)}, f32[10000,5000]{0,1:T(8,128)},
> f32[10000,5000]{0,1:T(8,128)}) Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label:
> %fusion.6 = (f32[10000,5000]{0,1:T(8,128)},
> f32[10000,5000]{0,1:T(8,128)}, f32[10000,5000]{0,1:T(8,128)})
> fusion(f32[10000,5000]{0,1:T(8,128)} %get-tuple-element.149,
> f32[]{:T(256)} %divide.5, f32[10000,5000]{0,1:T(8,128)}
> %get-tuple-element.166, f32[]{:T(... Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 11. Size: 4.0K Operator: op_type="ResourceApplyAdam" op_name="training/Adam/Adam/update_dense2/bias/ResourceApplyAdam"
> Shape: (f32[5000]{0:T(1024)}, f32[5000]{0:T(1024)},
> f32[5000]{0:T(1024)}) Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label: %fusion.44 =
> (f32[5000]{0:T(1024)}, f32[5000]{0:T(1024)}, f32[5000]{0:T(1024)})
> fusion(f32[5000]{0:T(1024)} %get-tuple-element.148, f32[]{:T(256)}
> %divide.5, f32[5000]{0:T(1024)} %get-tuple-element.164, f32[]{:T(256)}
> %subtract.24, f32[5000]{0:T(1024)} %ge... Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 12. Size: 4.0K Shape: (f32[]{:T(256)}, f32[]{:T(256)}, f32[5000]{0:T(1024)}, f32[2000]{0:T(1024)}, f32[10000]{0:T(1024)},
> f32[10000,128]{1,0:T(8,128)}, f32[1]{0:T(256)},
> f32[2000,1]{0,1:T(2,128)}) Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label:
> %all-reduce.13 = (f32[]{:T(256)}, f32[]{:T(256)},
> f32[5000]{0:T(1024)}, f32[2000]{0:T(1024)}, f32[10000]{0:T(1024)},
> f32[10000,128]{1,0:T(8,128)}, f32[1]{0:T(256)},
> f32[2000,1]{0,1:T(2,128)}) all-reduce(f32[]{:T(256)} %multiply.2,
> f32[]{:T(256)} %multiply.... Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 13. Size: 4.0K Operator: op_type="BiasAddGrad" op_name="training/Adam/gradients/gradients/dense_1/BiasAdd_grad/BiasAddGrad"
> Shape: (f32[10000]{0:T(1024)}, bf16[25,10000]{1,0:T(8,128)(2,1)})
> Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label: %fusion.137 = (f32[10000]{0:T(1024)},
> bf16[25,10000]{1,0:T(8,128)(2,1)})
> fusion(bf16[25,5000]{1,0:T(8,128)(2,1)} %get-tuple-element.137,
> f32[10000,5000]{0,1:T(8,128)} %get-tuple-element.149,
> f32[25,10000]{1,0:T(8,128)} %fusion.20), kind=kOutput, calls=%fus...
> Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 14. Size: 4.0K Operator: op_type="BiasAddGrad" op_name="training/Adam/gradients/gradients/dense2_1/BiasAdd_grad/BiasAddGrad" Shape: (f32[5000]{0:T(1024)}, bf16[25,5000]{1,0:T(8,128)(2,1)})
> Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label: %fusion.136 = (f32[5000]{0:T(1024)},
> bf16[25,5000]{1,0:T(8,128)(2,1)}) fusion(f32[5000,2000]{1,0:T(8,128)}
> %get-tuple-element.151, f32[2000]{0:T(1024)} %reshape.10,
> f32[25]{0:T(256)} %bitcast.1, f32[25,2000]{1,0:T(8,128)}
> %get-tuple-element.135, f32[25,500... Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 15. Size: 4.0K Operator: op_type="Sum" op_name="loss_1/output_loss/Sum" Shape: (f32[]{:T(256)},
> f32[]{:T(256)}) Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label: %fusion.103 =
> (f32[]{:T(256)}, f32[]{:T(256)}) fusion(f32[25,1]{0,1:T(2,128)}
> %get-tuple-element.133, f32[1]{0:T(256)} %get-tuple-element.157,
> f32[25]{0:T(256)} %get-tuple-element.134), kind=kLoop,
> calls=%fused_computation.101, metadata={op_type="Sum" op_n...
> Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 16. Size: 4.0K Shape: (f32[]{:T(256)}, f32[25,1]{0,1:T(2,128)}, f32[25,1]{0,1:T(2,128)}) Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label: %fusion.133 =
> (f32[]{:T(256)}, f32[25,1]{0,1:T(2,128)}, f32[25,1]{0,1:T(2,128)})
> fusion(f32[1]{0:T(256)} %get-tuple-element.157, f32[25]{0:T(256)}
> %get-tuple-element.134, u32[25,1]{0,1:T(2,128)}
> %get-tuple-element.146, u32[25,1]{0,1:T(2,128)} %get-tuple-el...
> Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 17. Size: 4.0K Shape: (f32[25]{0:T(256)}, f32[25,2000]{1,0:T(8,128)}) Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label: %fusion.31 = (f32[25]{0:T(256)},
> f32[25,2000]{1,0:T(8,128)}) fusion(f32[2000]{0:T(1024)} %reshape.10,
> f32[2000]{0:T(1024)} %get-tuple-element.150,
> f32[25,5000]{1,0:T(8,128)} %fusion.24, f32[5000,2000]{1,0:T(8,128)}
> %get-tuple-element.151), kind=kOutput, ca... Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 18. Size: 4.0K Shape: u32[8,128]{1,0} Unpadded size: 4.0K XLA label: constant literal Allocation type: global
> ==========================
> 
> 19. Size: 1.0K Operator: op_type="ResourceApplyAdam" op_name="training/Adam/Adam/update_dense2/bias/ResourceApplyAdam"
> Shape: f32[]{:T(256)} Unpadded size: 4B Extra memory due to padding:
> 1020B (256.0x expansion) XLA label: %subtract.14 = f32[]{:T(256)}
> subtract(f32[]{:T(256)} %constant.69, f32[]{:T(256)}
> %get-tuple-element.178), metadata={op_type="ResourceApplyAdam"
> op_name="training/Adam/Adam/update_dense2/bias/ResourceApplyAdam"}
> Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 20. Size: 1.0K Operator: op_type="ResourceApplyAdam" op_name="training/Adam/Adam/update_dense2/bias/ResourceApplyAdam"
> Shape: f32[]{:T(256)} Unpadded size: 4B Extra memory due to padding:
> 1020B (256.0x expansion) XLA label: %divide.5 = f32[]{:T(256)}
> divide(f32[]{:T(256)} %multiply.11, f32[]{:T(256)} %subtract.22),
> metadata={op_type="ResourceApplyAdam"
> op_name="training/Adam/Adam/update_dense2/bias/ResourceApplyAdam"}
> Allocation type: HLO temp
> ==========================
> 
> 
> TPU compilation failed [[node TPUReplicateMetadata (defined at
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748)
> ]] Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM
> happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for
> current allocation info.
> 
> 
> Original stack trace for 'TPUReplicateMetadata': File
> "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
> "__main__", mod_spec) File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in
> _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line
> 16, in <module> app.launch_new_instance() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 664, in launch_instance app.start() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line
> 477, in start ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888,
> in start handler_func(fd_obj, events) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py",
> line 277, in null_wrapper return fn(*args, **kwargs) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py",
> line 450, in _handle_events self._handle_recv() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py",
> line 480, in _handle_recv self._run_callback(callback, msg) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py",
> line 432, in _run_callback callback(*args, **kwargs) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py",
> line 277, in null_wrapper return fn(*args, **kwargs) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line
> 283, in dispatcher return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line
> 235, in dispatch_shell handler(stream, idents, msg) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line
> 399, in execute_request user_expressions, allow_stdin) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line
> 196, in do_execute res = shell.run_cell(code,
> store_history=store_history, silent=silent) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line
> 533, in run_cell return super(ZMQInteractiveShell,
> self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> line 2718, in run_cell interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler,
> result=result) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> line 2822, in run_ast_nodes if self.run_code(code, result): File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> line 2882, in run_code exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns,
> self.user_ns) File "<ipython-input-1-5929dd41a578>", line 104, in
> <module> epochs=5, verbose=1) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 727, in fit use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py",
> line 670, in fit validation_freq=validation_freq) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py",
> line 196, in experimental_tpu_fit_loop
> initial_loop_values=initial_loop_values) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py",
> line 1756, in experimental_run_steps_on_iterator initial_loop_values)
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/tpu_strategy.py",
> line 334, in _experimental_run_steps_on_iterator replicate_outputs =
> rewrite_fn() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/tpu_strategy.py",
> line 315, in rewrite_fn run_fn, replicate_inputs,
> device_assignment=self._device_assignment) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/tpu/tpu.py",
> line 639, in replicate maximum_shapes=maximum_shapes)[1] File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/tpu/tpu.py",
> line 927, in split_compile_and_replicate num_replicas=num_replicas,
> use_tpu=use_tpu, **metadata_kwargs) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_tpu_ops.py",
> line 6105, in tpu_replicate_metadata name=name) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper op_def=op_def) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py",
> line 507, in new_func return func(*args, **kwargs) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py",
> line 3357, in create_op attrs, op_def, compute_device) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py",
> line 3426, in _create_op_internal op_def=op_def) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py",
> line 1748, in __init__ self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Comment: Could you specify which error are you getting from the cases mentioned? Concrete logs would help. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I add the error message I got with the TPU when it is an out of memory !

Comment: this is kind of a convoluted question, with multiple inquiries. And it might be that some are based on some false assumptions. Let me clarify what I mean.

Comment: E.g. in regards to your assessments
`So in a way, can we say that it is like doing multi gpus computing with 8 gpus (each of 8gb of memory) ?`
`So does that mean having 8 gb hmb is totally different from 8 gb of VRAM ? `
HMB is a new architecture which uses interconnected DRAM in a way that achieves higher bandwidth while using less power in a substantially smaller form factor than DDR4 or GDDR5.

Comment: I believe that quantization and tensorflow are what makes you actually think of what possible differences might be in terms of memory “usability”.

These articles could be quite helpful as a starting point: 
[TPU architecture and Quantization in neural networks](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/an-in-depth-look-at-googles-first-tensor-processing-unit-tpu). And
[When to use TPU's](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tpus#when_to_use_tpus)